# How to get new line coverage percent in jest (not entire file %)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I've been using jest --coverage to calculate coverage for my code. I've added a `coverageThreshold` in jest.config.js but this only checks whole codebase/folder coverage.

I also tried jest `-o` (`--onlyChanged`) but this generates coverage percent for the entire file making actual new line coverage seem higher than it is.

Is there any way to check `jest --coverage` coverage percentage on **new lines only** (not changed lines)??

EXAMPLE: whole file coverage example, will pass global threshold of 95%. one new if statement line, didn't write a test for:

```
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files     |   96.15 |    95.83 |     100 |   95.83 |                   
changeFile.tsx|   96.15 |    95.83 |     100 |   95.83 | 119               
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------



EXAMPLE: as supposed to NEW line coverage example, will fail if global threshold is 95%, fails due to one of the lines not covered.
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File          | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered New Line #s 
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------   
changeFile.tsx|   50.00 |     100  |  100    |  100    | 1/2               
--------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

tried:

jest `-o` (`--onlyChanged`) , --lastCommit, --changedSince

but they only calculate coverage percent of entire changed file

---

If theres other coverage tools that can accomplish this, suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: Cloud you please let me know if you've located any solution?

Comment: Not possible yet locally. ended up removing new line threshold and depending on git sourcing for reviewers to see new line coverage during cr process.